# What should I do? The result will not change after refreshing the page. React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

What should I do? The results will not change after refreshing the page.

I have successfully authenticated the response from the server. But after refreshing the page, the data stored in the results disappear.

Is there any solution to this problem?

### MENU.js

```
 renderData = () => {
    try {
      const { results, isFetching } = this.props.loginReducer;
      const {pathname} = this.props.location;
      return (
        !isFetching &&
        results.data.u_status === 1 ? 
        (
          <li className={pathname === '/member' ? 'nav-item' : null}>
            <Link to="/member" className="nav-link">
                  <i className="nav-icon fas fa-user-circle" />
                  <p>&nbsp; พนักงาน / Member</p>
            </Link>  
          </li>
        )
        : null 
      )
  } catch (error) {
}}
```

### login.action.js

```
export const login = (history, credential) => {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(setLoginStateToFetching());
    let result = await httpClient.post(server.LOGIN_URL, credential);
    if (result.data.result === OK) {
      localStorage.setItem(server.LOGIN_PASSED, YES)
      getState().appReducer.app.forceUpdate();
      history.push('/report')
      dispatch(setLoginStateToSuccess(result.data));
      console.log(result.data)
    } else {
      dispatch(setLoginStateToFailed());
    }
  }
}
```

### login.reducer.js

```
const initialState = {
  results: null,
  isFetching: false,
  isError: false,
};

export default (state = initialState, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case HTTP_LOGIN_FETCHING:
      return { ...state, results: null, isFetching: true, isError: false };
    case HTTP_LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, results: payload, isFetching: false, isError: false };
    case HTTP_LOGIN_FAILED:
      return { ...state, results: null, isFetching: false, isError: true };
      case HTTP_STOCK_EDIT_INITIALED:
        return { ...state, isInitialed: payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Thanks for your advice

Comment: Can you please show the code where you are connecting your store with app? or can you put your code in codesandbox so that it will be easier to go through!

Comment: Why do you need to refresh the page? After refreshing the page, the redux store is not persisted, hence all the redux data will anyways gonna be disappeared. Also, why do you need to do forceUpdate()? Whenever you dispatch some data in the redux, the redux store updates itself!

Comment: That I use to forceUpdate () get the components menu and header to show

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After successful authentication, you probably have an authentication token with users data which you can store in the **cookies** or **localStorage** or **SessionStorage**.

Let's assume you store a token in cookies, so every time when the page is refreshed you need to check if a cookie exists. If a cookie exists, you will need to populate data using redux.

- Create **authenticate** method in redux. That method will be responsible for the authentication process.
- Every time when the page is refreshed you will be calling the authentication method. The authentication method is responsible for checking if a
  the cookie exists that will be populating the global store.
- If a cookie doesn't exist you will be redirected to the login page where you will call a login method.
- After successful authentication, you need to save the results into a cookie (it depends what you get from the API)
- If you use localStorage or SessionStorage you can use JSON.stringify(...)) to store the object. which you can decode on checking.